# Function to create a calendar for one year with gaps (date and days in separate cells)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is it possible to have a function within a Google Docs spreadsheet which I can link to a button which will create a calendar in the following format:

[image]

Number will be 1 - 365 for the days
Date will be starting from 01.01.2021 - 31.12.2021
Day will be the corresponding day for the date

After each day there have to be 3 empty cells as in the picture

If I try to just select and use the auto fill it does not work, so my idea was a function I can link to a button and use it to generate a new calendar sheet for one year.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Yes it's possible by using Google Apps Script. If you need further help please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question does not require a script. The OP is correct that "autofill" does not work. However a simple copy/paste do the job. The key is to copy not only the "calendar" row but also the "2 x blank rows" following the calendar row. This will ensure that every calendar entry is separated by 2 blank rows.

The target row must be calculated in advance. It will also enable the user to make sure that  there are sufficient rows created in the sheet.

| Number of days    | 365   |
|---    |---    |
| Rows per day  | 3     |
|   | 1095  |
| Plus header rows  | 4     |
| Target row    | 1099  |
**Procedure**

- Make sure that there are 1,099 rows in the sheet
- Create Day #2

  - Number: `=A5+1` - format as Number, Automatic
  - Date: `=B5+1` - format as Number, Date
  - Day: `=B8` - format as Number, Day
- Select the range A8:C10. This is the range for day#2 including the 2 blank rows.

  - Select `Edit, Copy`
- Select the range A11:A1099

  - Select `Edit, Paste`